# Where are JDBC4 annotations?

Tags: java, jdbc, annotations

Some time ago, jdk 6 announced JDBC4 with the "[Annotation-Based SQL Queries](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/08/02/jjdbc-4-enhancements-in-java-se-6.html?page=2)".
I was looking for testing the approach but didn't find the required classes (like java.sql.BasicQuery) in the JDK 6.  Googling a little on the subject, I found a thread on java.net that tells these "Ease of User" features haven't finally been included in the JDK because of a lack of time.  Does someone here tell me more about the future availability of these features ?

Comment: I don't know what happened to that idea, but JPA (Java Persistence API) is based on annotations: http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/faq/persistence.jsp

Comment: If it goes anywhere, it looks like it will be for jdk 8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Annotation based SQL queries never made it into the final JDBC 4.0, and there havn't been much talk about bringing them back, work seems rather to have been focused on [JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/persistence.jsp).

If you still want something similar, look at [iBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/). [Here's](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-ibatis3/index.html?ca=drs-#java5) some examples

Answer (score 0):

[JLibs DAOPattern](http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/DAOPattern) provides similar functionality that you are looking for...